# Trouble accessing data passed from another view, using MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to pass data from one view to the other using MVC. I am trying to do a simple guessing game, where on the first view, we enter a range of numbers, then on the second view we try to guess the number. I am able to store the values in my model, but I'm having trouble accessing them/using them in a js script on another view. Sorry if this is too much code, MVC's are hard to ask for help on without showing a full range of code. When I go to the second view to guess the number, it doesn't recognize `@ViewBag.(model => model.Low)` and it says `Load is not defined`

### **Model**

```
pubblic class Range
{
    public int High
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["High"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["High"] = 3;
            }

            return (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["High"];

        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["High"] = value;
        }
    }


    public int Low
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Low"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["Low"] = 1;
            }

            return (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["Low"];

        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Low"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

### **Controller**

```
public class GuessingGameController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult EnterRange()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EnterRange(Range range)
    {
        int high = range.High;
        int low = range.Low;
        return View(range);
    }

    public ActionResult GuessNumber()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

### **View 1: Enter Range**

```
@model GameMVC.Models.Range

@using (Html.BeginForm("EnterRange", "GuessingGame"))
{
    <center>
        <h2>Lets play a game.</h2>

        Enter A Range of Numbers:
        <br />
        Low: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Low)
        <br />
        High: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.High)
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Enter"/>
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Now, To the Game", "GuessNumber", "GuessingGame")
        </p>
    </center>
}
```

### **View 2: Guess Number**

```
@model GameMVC.Models.Range
<script language="JavaScript">
    var myNum, count;

    function Load() {
        document.game.status.value = "Please set range of numbers and press the Start button.";
        document.game.number.focus();
    }

    function Round(scale) {

        var dd = new Date();
        return((Math.round(Math.abs(Math.sin(dd.getTime())) * 8.71 * scale) % scale));
    }

    function myRange() {
        var to = 1 + 1 * @ViewBag.(model => model.Low);
        count = 0;
        myNum = Round(to);
        while (myNum < @ViewBag.(model => model.High);)
            myNum = Round(to);
        document.game.status.value = "Please guess a number, enter it, and press Guess.";
    }

    function Guess() {
        var numberGuess = document.game.number.value;
        count++;
        if (numberGuess < myNum) alert("My number is greater than " + numberGuess + ".");
        else if (numberGuess > myNum) alert("My number is less than " + numberGuess + ".");
        else alert("It takes you " + count + " attempts to guess this number");
    }
</script>

<body onload=" Load() ">
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <form name=game>
        Guess: <input type="text" name="number" size=10>
        <p>
            <br/>
            <input type="button" value="Guess" onclick=" Guess() ">
        </p>

        @Html.Label("status")
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@ViewBag.(model => model.Low)`, you could try just using `@Model.Low`

Comment: unfortunately when I do that, I get an object is null error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Right, that error is occurring because you are not giving the "Guess Number" view a model to bind to. In the "GuessNumber()" method of your controller, you should pass the range into your view.

Here's a .NET Fiddle you can take a look at. https://dotnetfiddle.net/GSrgaU 

Although the code isn't completely functional, you'll notice that using `@Model.Low` or `@Model.High` binds the data in the model to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Model instance is not provided for "GuessAction" view. You need to pass an instance of "Range" to "GuessNumber" view. Since you are accessing values from session, you can simply pass a new instance.

```
 public ActionResult GuessNumber()
 {
     return View(new Range());
 }
```

Then in javascript you can simply access the data as @Model.High and @Model.Low

You can also use TempData to store the high and low values if you need it only for one request.